# Python Neomodel TypeError: Parameters of type UniqueIdProperty are not supported

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-ogm, neomodel

When saving my object, I am getting this error, and I don't know why, what am I doing wrong? As far as I can see, I am using the UniqueIdProperty according to the documentation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\data.py", line 337, in fix_parameters
    dehydrated, = dehydrator.dehydrate([parameters])
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\data.py", line 406, in dehydrate
    return tuple(map(dehydrate_, values))
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\data.py", line 402, in dehydrate_
    return {key: dehydrate_(value) for key, value in obj.items()}
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\data.py", line 402, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: dehydrate_(value) for key, value in obj.items()}
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\data.py", line 404, in dehydrate_
    raise TypeError(obj)
TypeError: <neomodel.properties.UniqueIdProperty object at 0x00000236B1E4C400>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\PycharmProjects\openPrecision\tests\manual_tests\test_model.py", line 16, in test_model
    course.save()
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neomodel\hooks.py", line 14, in hooked
    val = fn(self)
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neomodel\core.py", line 641, in save
    self.cypher(query, params)
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neomodel\core.py", line 488, in cypher
    return db.cypher_query(query, params)
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neomodel\util.py", line 35, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neomodel\util.py", line 309, in cypher_query
    response = session.run(query, params)
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\work\simple.py", line 217, in run
    self._autoResult._run(
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\work\result.py", line 77, in _run
    parameters = DataDehydrator.fix_parameters(
  File "C:\Users\LARJAEG\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\open-precision-da2OwAle-py3.10\lib\site-packages\neo4j\data.py", line 340, in fix_parameters
    raise TypeError("Parameters of type {} are not supported".format(type(value).__name__))
TypeError: Parameters of type UniqueIdProperty are not supported
```

This is my model class:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from neomodel import StructuredNode, UniqueIdProperty, Property, RelationshipTo, cardinality, StringProperty

from open_precision.core.model import DataModelBase

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from open_precision.core.model.path import Path


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Course(StructuredNode, DataModelBase):
    id: str = UniqueIdProperty()
    name: str = StringProperty(required=True)
    description: str = StringProperty(required=False)

    CONTAINS: RelationshipTo = RelationshipTo('open_precision.core.model.path.Path',
                                              'CONTAINS',
                                              cardinality=cardinality.ZeroOrMore)
```

This is the code that raises the error, it initiates a course and saves it:

```py
course = Course(name="test", description="bla")
course.save()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a hunch: `StructuredNode` class already has an id attribute which is mapped to the Neo4j's internal node id. Don't know what happens when you override this attribute. Try rename it to something else instead of id.

Comment: I figured it out myself a few days ago and forgot to answer here. However thank you for your help, it was exactly that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as [@Ferenc Pal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3786624/ferenc-pal) described, renaming the attribute has solved the issue.